# Silverlight WCF Service Stored Procedure

Tags: vb.net, wcf, silverlight, stored-procedures

I am trying to figure out how to call a Stored Procedure from my Silverlight application. I can call the database using this function:

```
<OperationContract()>
Public Function ImportData(
    ByVal authentication As AuthenticationArgs,
    ByVal caseID As String) As ResponseArgs(Of GetGuidelineData_Result)

    Dim guidelineDataResults As GetGuidelineData_Result
    Dim exception As ExceptionArgs = Nothing

    If AuthenticationService.CheckPermissions(authentication, exception, PermissionType.StateUser) Then

        Try
            Dim model As DCF_ACCESS_Model = DataHelper.CreateDCF_ACCESS_Model()

            model.GetGuidelineData(caseID)

        Catch ex As Exception

            Return New ResponseArgs(Of GetGuidelineData_Result)(New ExceptionArgs(ex.Message))

        End Try

        Return New ResponseArgs(Of GetGuidelineData_Result)(guidelineDataResults)

    Else

        Return New ResponseArgs(Of GetGuidelineData_Result)(exception)

    End If

End Function
```

How could I modify the code to call the stored procedure instead? The stored procedure, GetGuidelineData, takes 1 parameter as input.

Comment: Whay is your issue? Did you failed to call wcf service? Did your db call failed? What is error details? . . .

Comment: @evgenyl - I had no error, just that I didn't know how to make a call to the stored procedure. But I have finally figured it out through some trial and error.

Comment: Good luck! Consider to add your answer - may be it wi help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to call the stored procedure with the following:

```
<OperationContract()>
Public Function ImportData(
    ByVal authentication As AuthenticationArgs,
    ByVal caseID As String) As ResponseArgs(Of GetGuidelineData_Result)

    Dim guidelineDataResults As GetGuidelineData_Result
    Dim exception As ExceptionArgs = Nothing

    If AuthenticationService.CheckPermissions(authentication, exception, PermissionType.StateUser) Then

        Try
            Dim model As DCF_ACCESS_Model = DataHelper.CreateDCF_ACCESS_Model()

            ' Call stored procedure
            guidelineDataResults = model.GetGuidelineData(caseID).First()

        Catch ex As Exception

            Return New ResponseArgs(Of GetGuidelineData_Result)(New ExceptionArgs(ex.ToString()))

        End Try

        Return New ResponseArgs(Of GetGuidelineData_Result)(guidelineDataResults)

    Else

        Return New ResponseArgs(Of GetGuidelineData_Result)(exception)

    End If


End Function
```

the call to the stored procedure is done with:

```
 model.GetGuidelineData(caseID).First()
```

It gets the first element in the collection and returns it as its output.